# Cross platform speech recognition for python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Is there a cross platform speech recognition software for python? I have found a few for windows, and although my system is windows I do not like using Microsoft's speech recognition. Are there any free alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps the [wikipedia article on `List of speech recognition software`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software) would be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

[pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) has SWIG bindings for Python.